# Load all data to jQuery autocomplete at once

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete and on each key pressed it requests data from the given URL. How can I provide data to autocomplete by accessing the database only once at page load?

**code**

```
$("#cls").autocomplete({
    source: 'classes.htm'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array as source value:

```
source: ["item1","item2"]
```

Comment: ya that is true, i thought there would be something that autocompleter could handle, thanks